# 2 aliens walk on a line meeting probability.

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

2 aliens walk on a line randomly. At each timestep they walk independently either left or right (1 meter) with equal probability. They start 10 meters apart. What's the probability that after 7 time steps they have met(Passed though the same point)?

Hello,

I'm trying to solve this puzzle but I'm struggling. I know that there are $4^7$ states in the tree. If we imagine them being on a number line. Alien A starting at $0$ and Alien B starting at $10$. I know that they can only meet at points 3-7.

I know that the probability of Alien A getting to 3 after 3 time steps is $\frac{1}{8}$.

I don't really know where to go from here. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: "I know that the probability of Alien A getting to 3 after 3 time steps is 1/6" - did you mean 1/8?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean they cannot both walk in the same direction? Otherwise, it would seem the problem reduces to one alien on a line.  Even if they can walk in the same direction, it reduces to one alien with a 0 step option, since you are only concerned with relative motion.

Comment: @ajcr Correct :) Thank you

Comment: @CraigHicks I didn't specify the problem very well. Each alien can either walk towards or away from the other at each time step. They are both independant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135578/265466