# Probability question of ants movement

Tags: probability

$2$ ants are $10$cm apart on a straight line. At each step, each ant can move 1cm to the left with a $0.5$ probability or the to the right with the $0.5$ probability.

> What is the probability that they collide after $7$ steps?

I understand for them to collide both ants can either move:

- $5$ steps towards each other or
- $6$ steps for $ant1$ towards $ant2$ and $4$ steps for $ant2$ towards $ant1$
  or
- $4$ steps for $ant1$ towards $ant2$ and $6$ steps for $ant2$ towards $ant1$
  or
- $7$ steps for $ant1$ towards $ant2$ and $3$ steps for $ant2$ towards $ant1$
  or
- $3$ steps for $ant1$ towards $ant2$ and $7$ steps for $ant2$ towards $ant1$

Is this the right approach or is there something I'm missing? Maybe an easier way?

I am also confused as to how '$7$ steps' affect the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is close... but notice that ant 1 cannot move a net distance of 6 over the course of 7 steps.  If you label the spaces the ants can sit like a checkerboard you should see that each timestep the color the ant resides on will change color.  To make calculations easier, I recommend looking at this instead of the location of the ants or how each ant individually acts to instead look at the net distance between them.  The ants will move closer together in a single time step with what probability?  The ants will remain the same distance apart with what probability?  Move farther apart?

Comment: Continue just as you would for any other random-walk or drunken-random-walk problem.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135578/265466, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2191128/265466, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2191612/265466 and likely others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At each step, with probability $1/2$ the distance of the two ants remains unchanged.  With probability $1/4$ it increases by $2$ cm, and with probability $1/4$ it decreases by $2$ cm.

My reading of the problem is that we want the probability that the ants collide after *exactly* $7$ steps.  This is different from the probability of colliding in *at most* $7$ steps.  The basic ingredients of the solution are the same, but they are mixed in different proportions.

The two ants collide the first time the number of steps in which they approach exceeds the number of steps in which they move away from each other by $5$.

Moreover, the last step must decrease the distance.  This means that we are interested in ways to decrease the distance to $2$ cm in six step.  There are two ways to go about this:

- We may decrease the distance $4$ times and keep it the same twice.  This can be done in $\binom{6}{4} = \binom{6}{2}$ ways.
- We may increase the distance once within the first five steps, and decrease it the other five times.  This can be done in $\binom{5}{1}$ ways.

Since the events we have described are mutually exclusive, we just add the probabilities:

$$ \left[\binom{6}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^4 \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2 + \binom{5}{1} \Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^5\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)\right]\frac{1}{4} \enspace, $$

where the $1/4$ outside the square brackets accounts for the seventh step.  This formula simplifies to $\frac{65}{4^7}$, which is approximately $0.004$.

---

If we also want to consider the probability of colliding after $5$ or $6$ steps, we include two more events:

- The ants move toward each other for $5$ consecutive steps.  There is just one way of doing this.
- The ants keep their distance in one of the first five steps, but otherwise move toward each other.  This can be done in $\binom{5}{1}$ ways.

The probability of the union of these disjoint events is:

$$ \Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^5 + \binom{5}{1}\Big(\frac{1}{4}\Big)^5\frac{1}{2} = \frac{56}{4^7} \enspace. $$

All in all, we get $\frac{121}{4^7}$, which is approximately $0.0074$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Fabio. I am still confused about the '7 steps' remark. This is the exact wording of the question: _ "What is the probability that after 7 time steps, the ants have met one another (i.e., passed through the same point)?"_

Comment: OK, that is a little different from my initial reading.  One needs to include also the probability of colliding after 5 or 6 steps.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'keep the distance the same twice" eg We may decrease the distance 4 times and keep it the same twice?

Comment: If both ants move left or both move right (each has probability $1/4$) then the distance stays the same.